# window.event alternative for Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, cross-browser

I've searched and tried all the answers that I found about it here, but I think my case is a little different as nothing worked.

I have this element:

```
<circle id="circle" cx="800" cy="400" r="70" />
```

I dynamically change it's cx and cy attributes based on my mouse position, using:

```
getCoordinateX = function() {
  return window.event.clientX;
};

getCoordinateY = function() {
  return window.event.clientY;
};

creative.dom.circle.setAttribute('cx', getCoordinateX());
creative.dom.circle.setAttribute('cy', getCoordinateY());
```

This works on every browser I tested, except Firefox, and although I've read the reasons why, I still couldn't find an alternative. Any ideas?

Edit:

I am using this a well:

```
creative.dom.mainImage.addEventListener('mousemove', getCoordinateX);
creative.dom.mainImage.addEventListener('mousemove', getCoordinateY);
```

Comment: Define a function parameter named `event` for your event handlers. Using `window.event` should never be necessary, except in working with some specific very old browsers.

Comment: ...oh wait, you're not using those as event handlers, so I'm not understanding your code. Shouldn't you be running some code in a `mousemove` handler?

Comment: Yes, I am using it as an EventListener. I edited my post with them, sorry.

Comment: Oh OK, so you're relying on the last value set when calling it directly. To make it compatible, you'll need to define shared variables that the event handlers update when an event takes place, and then use those variables when/where needed.

Comment: ...maybe something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ymbjt7d2/

Comment: That worked perfectly, I just didn't use the setInterval because I want it to be updated all time. Thank you!